# How to get integer?

Tags: python, integer

As a new python programmer. I try to create and solve problems myself. I use Python 3.

Here's the code:

```
def next():
    print ("how_much="),
    if input = 50:
        print("Nice, you're not greedy, you win"),
    else:
        print("You greedy bastard!")
```

I want to convert the value to integer and print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win" if the number is 50. otherwise print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win".

I inspired to create above code based on this code:

```
def is_int(x):
    print round(x),
    if x == round(x):
        print 'True',
    else:
        print 'False'

is_int(7.0)   # True
is_int(7.5)   # False
is_int(-1)    # True
```

Comment: 1. Use `==` for comparison, `=` for assignment 2. you are shadowing the function `next` 3. you have an unnecessary trailing comma after `True`. But most importantly it isn't clear what your question is.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You need to use `input` (or `raw_input` for Python 2.7) to get users to be able to interact with your program (`print` doesn't allow them to respond). You also have `if how_much = 50:` which will fail, because you need to use `==` for comparisons. Your code for `is_int()` seems to do what you want. What exactly are you asking as there's no question, just a statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need add [int()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert to integer, and change '=' (assignment) to '=='(comparing)

```
def next_int(x)
    input = int(x) # convert string to integer
    if input == 50:
        print("Nice, you're not greedy, you win")
    else:
        print("You greedy bastard!")
```

Comment: There is no actual question in the original post, and I'm not sure what this addresses. Also, this code has multiple errors (`print ("how much:" + x)` does nothing useful because it doesn't elicit a response from a user).

Comment: yeah, the original post is quite vague. But based on the code the OP used, it doesn't look like he needs to get input from user - mentioned function also doesn't take any input from user. But i get your point.

Comment: guys all I try to do is,                                                                                                         if next_int(50) it will print "Nice, you're not greedy, you win"                                            otherwise it will print "You greedy bastard!"

Comment: I don't copy and paste. I created an original code from inspiring other code which I found here on stack overflow

Comment: @PravinNath i edited my answer, it should do what you want now. Please also edit the initial question so it isn't vague.

Comment: @PravinNath please write if you want Python 2 or Python 3 code (your example code is in Python 2, but "your" code is in Python 2)

Comment: @PravinNath and explicitly specify the input is specified through argument in function and from user input in cmd
also accept this(or other) answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @whoknows your code solved the problem and please add : in the end of def next_int(x)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to find out if a variable is a an int you can just do this:
(works on python 2.7, check on 3..)

```
def is_int(x):
     return type(x) == int
```